# Equation of a tangent

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am asked to find the equation of the tangent line (or plane) at the given point.

$f(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+3z^2=6$ at $(1,-1,1)$.

I have computed that $\nabla f(x,y,z)=(2x,4y,6z)=(2,-4,6)$ at $(1,-1,1)$.

I know this vector is normal to the surface, I don't know what to do now in order to find the tangent though.

Comment: Try to use the fact that tangent plane and normal are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ then the plane equation can always be obtained by,

$$ \langle (x,y,z)-(x_0,y_0,z_0) \rangle \cdot \nabla f_{p_0} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

If your normal vector is (a, b, c) then your tangent plane will be

ax+by+cz = a constant.

Fit the constant to the point on the surface where the plane is tangent.  Done.